# In PHP how to make str_word_count() to recognize all UTF-8 special characters as words?

Tags: php, string, function, utf-8, special-characters

Consider the following program:

```
 <?php
     $str='You & I = We';
     $arr=[];
     $arr=str_word_count($str,2,"&=");
     foreach($arr as $key=>$value){
               echo $key.'&nbsp;&nbsp;===>&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$value.'<br>';
     }
?>
```

Output:

```
0  ===>  You
4  ===>  &
6  ===>  I
8  ===>  =
10 ===>  We
```

Now consider the following program:

```
 <?php
     $str='You & I = We';
     $arr=[];
     $arr=str_word_count($str,2);
     foreach($arr as $key=>$value){
               echo $key.'&nbsp;&nbsp;===>&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$value.'<br>';
     }
?>
```

Output:

```
0  ===>  You
6  ===> I
10  ===> We
```

**NOTE:**

The difference between 1st and 2nd function is that in 1st function third argument

`"&="`

is present but in 2nd function it is not.

As such the 1st function recognizes the special characters `&` and `=` as words but 2nd function does not.

Now consider a situation where our string has lots and lots of special characters. It may become impractical to include all of them in the third argument.

So here is my question:

Is there any simpler way to make `str_word_count()` function recognize all UTF-8 special characters as words without going through the trouble of including a mammoth number of special characters in third argument?

Comment: Can't you explode om space. Then possibly do a strpos to find the location of the exploded "word"?

Comment: As @Andreas said. Explode the string by space and you will have a nicely array with all words, so a word would be by identifying a space between other words. For example: `You are the best @ SO.`, if you do `$words = explode(' ', $that_string);` and then `echo count($words);` you would get `6` words. But final word would be `SO.`, not `SO`.

Comment: @matiaslauriti both of you are right. Fist I have to use explode to seperate all the elements seperated by space into elements of an array and then a loop and strpos to find the position of each array element in the original string. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @cyano_learner Yes. Do you need help with it?

Comment: No thanks, I can do it

Comment: @cyano_learner Note that I updated my answer after you accepted. I noticed an error. I had to add "+1" at $nextpos line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it.

https://3v4l.org/r4ngg

As I wrote in comments you can use explode and strpos() to get the words and positions of the words.
Using the third perimeter of strpos(), offset makes sure you do not get the position of an incorrect word.
$nextpos will always be the position of end of the previous word, that way even if you repeat the same word twice, it will still show the correct position.

```
$str ="this is a very very long text with some words repeating over and over & over again. When you use Explode() you will get an array with all the words. & using strpos( haystack, needle, & most importantly offset) you should get a good array with the positions of the words.";

$arrWords = explode(" ", $str);

$nextpos = 0;
$arrPos =array();
for ($i=0; $i <= count($arrWords)-1; $i++){

    $arrPos[$i]["Position"] = strpos($str, $arrWords[$i], $nextpos);
    $arrPos[$i]["Lenght"] = strlen($arrWords[$i]);
    $arrPos[$i]["Word"] = $arrWords[$i];
    $nextpos= $nextpos+strlen($arrWords[$i])+1;
}

var_dump($arrPos);
```